# Python- can I split a string with str.split after the first integer?

Tags: python

I have some strings that look like this:

text-text-text-12345

but the number of "text"'s are not the same so I don't want to string split on "-"

Is there any way I can split on the first appearance of a number, so I have the string

text-text-text-?

I am thinking about using regular expressions but I would love to figure out if str.split can deal with this problem.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Splitting implies getting multiple pieces out, your example only gets the first piece. Perhaps you don't require the second (and subsequent) pieces?

Comment: No, [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) cannot deal with this.  You'd need to use `re`.

Comment: Can you explain your problem in more details? It seems the solution would be `string.rsplit(your_string, "-", 1)`, but it might not be as easy.

Comment: @PritamBaral, sorry I forgot to include that I would grab only the first piece. Perhaps with list comprehension. Thanks. I will use re.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'(?<=\d)\D', 'start 123 after text', maxsplit=1)
['start 123', 'after text']
```

It looks for the first non-number after a digit (0-9) and splits there, with at most 1 split occuring.

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
for (i, c) in enumerate(s):
    if c.isdigit():
        break   
else:
    raise ValueError('input with no number part')

fields = s[:i].split('-')
```

Comment: A regex would be much better than that. This is python, not battery-less assembly, after all.

Comment: Obligatory quote of JWZ: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems.

Comment: Wow, this^ is perhaps the worst usage of that quote I have ever seen. Let me justify why. Regex is a solution that fits this problem perfectly.And a simple regex at that. Trying to apply that quote here is like saying regex itself is a problem outright.

Comment: That quote was used with an implied smiley ;) but I don't agree that just asserting "Regex is a solution that fits this problem perfectly" will change minds.